# How do I look for a particular text in file and then return it's respected file name when found in Python?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a text file with the following content,

```
f: 1.pdf
t: abc
f: 2.pdf
t: as, as
asd
f: 3.pdf
t: found
f: 4.pdf
t: .,ad
.ads
f: 5.pdf
t: ad
f: 6.pdf
t: ...
```

I want my python script to read this text file and if it finds the word "found" then I want to write the file name above into the output file. Like in the above example, script would write 3.pdf in the output file because below it there's a word "found".

I think it would require using a loop and regex to match the word? I have a slight idea but don't know how to begin.

Comment: It is always guaranteed that lines will alternate between `f: ....` and `t: ...`, starting with `f: ....`?

Comment: Yes. But line `t: ..` may follow by multiple random lines before reaching line `f: ...`

Comment: Thank you. Second question: is it okay to read the whole file into memory at once, or do you need to avoid doing that?

Comment: I guess it would be ok but I think reading line by line would be better? But as long as script gives the desired output it wouldn't matter much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can use this context manager:

```
with open('text.txt','r') as s, open('output.txt','w') as f:
    lns = s.read().splitlines()
    t = [lns[i-1].split(': ')[1] for i,ln in enumerate(lns) if ln.endswith(': found')]
    f.write('\n'.join(t))
```

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

If you want it more clear:

```
with open('text.txt','r') as s:
    lines = s.read().splitlines()
    
files = []
for i,line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.endswith(': found'):
        files.append(lines[i-1].split(': ')[1])

with open('output.txt','w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(files))
```

Comment: Thank you. But I am getting this error on second line: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 54170: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: Are you using `txt` files?

Comment: Yes. Seems like it was encoding related issue so I specified encoding format on the first line and it worked.

`with open('text.txt','r', encoding="utf8") as s:`

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

This suggested approach is based on the clarifications that the line with `t:`  will immediately follow the line with `f:` , and that it is preferable to have a solution that loops through the file rather than reading it all into memory.

Regular expression parsing is not required in this situation.  The only complicating factor is that pairs of lines must be considered, rather than a line at a time.  This is easily addressed by storing the value of the previous line in another variable, which is copied from the current line at the end of the loop, ready for the next iteration.

```
previous_line = None

with open("myinput") as fin:
    with open("myoutput", "w") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            line = line.strip()
            if (line == "t: found"
                and previous_line is not None
                and previous_line.startswith("f: ")):

                fout.write(previous_line[3:] + "\n")

            previous_line = line
```

Because the line is pre-processed with `strip`, if there was any trailing whitespace after "found", this will have been removed.

Comment: Thanks for this! Though I am getting the warning on line 11 `Value "previous_line" is unsubscriptable`

But it works so, thanks a lot! :D

Comment: @RickK Did you run it? `pylint` is quite simply wrong here. It is worried about reaching that line with `previous_line = None`, but the `previous_line is not None` in the `if` test excludes that possibility.

Comment: @RickK. If you follow the logic in this code, you will see that the line will only get executed when `previous_line` is a string -- so it is subscriptable.

Comment: @RickK. One can silence that error from pylint by initialising `previous_line = ""` instead of `previous_line = None` for example, and if you follow the logic through you'll see that the code would actually work (because an empty string doesn't start with `"f: "`). But it would be less appropriate than `None` here, because it would imply that the previous line actually existed and was empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation!